# Picker View, how to return index of the selected item. Swift 4

Tags: swift, uibutton, uipickerview

I tried to return the index of the selected item in picker View, but I did not succeed. I need to transfer the index of the element when I click the button, then, depending on the index, call a specific function.

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let row = [pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
}
```

I tried to print the value of row into the console and it turned out, but when I try to create a condition if row = 0 and etc. I get an error. Help me please!

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: you need to use double equal for comparison `if row == 0`

Comment: @ronatory I found a mistake. It was necessary to do so : If row == [0]

Comment: Do you really need to embed `selectedRow(inComponent:)` into an array? It will be always an array with a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var row: Int = 0
var repeatPickerData = [Any]()
var repeatPickerView: UIPickerView?
if let aComponent = repeatPickerView?.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) {
    row = aComponent
}
strPrintRepeat = repeatPickerData[row]
```